# I can't connect watcher to openstack

Tags: openstack, keystone

I have the following scenario:

```
server: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
openstack installed with devstack
watcher 2.2.0
```

Every services seem to be working and i can see the watcher dashboard on localhost.

But I think I have an auth problem between watcher and keystone :

```
Error contacting Watcher server: Unable to establish connection 
to http://x.x.x.x:9322/v1/services: HTTPConnectionPool(host='x.x.x.x', port=9322):
 Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/services (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.
HTTP Connection object at 0x7fba33b1be50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connexion refusée')). 
Attempt 6 of 6
```

I'm testing something on a VM, I put the same IP and the same password everywhere

Where should I look first ?

Comment: check the network `host='x.x.x.x', port=9322` could communicate.

Comment: @VictorLee The telnet is working

Comment: The main point is dashboard can't access? You should check the `apache` or `keepalived` service first, look for the essential cause by the logs step by step. Could you post any more detail about that?

Comment: I can't access to watcher with the terminal or the dashboard.
Apache is running.
I have an error 500 when i try to reach watcher services